# Risk of getting shocked by ECG leads?

Tags: safety, isolation, shock, ecg, medical

I have recently come into possession of a GE patient monitor (Eagle 4000) which looks structurally sound, probably decommissioned because of its age. It seems to work without a hiccup but I remembered from a DIY ECG project that you shouldn't hook up electrodes from your chest to anything powered by mains voltage, for safety reasons. While I'm sure professional medical devices like this have excellent isolation I figured I wouldn't use it unless powered from a battery. Are my worries in place or would it be okay to use it normally?

The device was serviced in 2014.

I live in a 230V country.

Comment: Medical devices like ECG are class IV devices so the leakage current into the patient is abysmally small.

Comment: I'm worried about how you acquired this device and whether it's safe at all.

Comment: @Andyaka Worked a summer job at a hospital, they let me keep some of the stuff that was waiting around to be discarded. The monitor is 20 years old, they got newer stuff now. Pretty sure they expected me to just disassemble it. It seems to work fine but I'll rather play it safe since I don't understand the inner workings.

Comment: I'd consider the risk rather low if there aren't signs of physical damage. Medical devices are designed to have a multitude of safety measures preventing line voltage form entering patient or examiner body. BUT safety of these devices also relies on regular service and testing. So you won't get a reliable recommendation without a proper test of the device. Only by testing according to manufacturer's spec you can find out, if some safety measure has failed or not. To sum it up: why try your luck?

Comment: Aside from the content, your question is off-topic due to different issues. It deals with the use of a device, hence it's not an engineering related topic. The question also spans a lot of questions and is therefore difficult to address with a single answer. And, as you can see from the comments, it will elicit opininons more likely than facts. Try to keep those aspects in mind for future questions.

Comment: @Ariser I figured that if anyone knows the answer it'd be people who know how these devices work, felt like electronics is the closest exchange to my problem so I tried it here. But yeah, I'm gonna be careful, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that @Ariser summed it up pretty well so I'm closing the question.

Comment: Hi, On it's own, this isn't an *answer* as the details are elsewhere. I see that you got what you need from a comment *and* that site member couldn't write an answer now anyway, as the question has been voted closed. In this situation, it would be appropriate for you to quote the relevant part(s) of the comment(s) in your answer. So can you please (a) copy the relevant part(s) of the comment(s) into your answer; (b) highlight the copied text in your answer & hit Ctrl+Q to add the blockquote to it; (c) add a link to that comment (right click the time of the comment -> copy link address). Thanks